Files inside assets folder not working in development environment
I am trying to setup an existing project in my new machine (apple M3 pro).
The project is using ruby 2.7.7, Rails 5.2.1
The code is as follows
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'active_admin_logged_out', media: 'all' %>

    <!--Montserrat Font family -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'active_admin_logged_out' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <title>sasa</title>
</head>

Once i start the project the files inside assets are not loading.

The file paths are as follows
app/assets/javascripts/active_admin_logged_out.js

 app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin_logged_out.scss

It is working if i define it as follows.
<script src="/assets/active_admin_logged_out.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/active_admin_logged_out.css">

Any idea on how to fix this?
